# get Podio Activity / all revision API

Tags: podio

Is there an API call to get all fields revisions? Just like the activity on Podio?

The [get all revisions](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-revisions-22372) return individual ID and no details.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, there is no API call to get all field revisions with values.
You have to call [Get item revision difference](https://developers.podio.com/doc/items/get-item-revision-difference-22374) API call to get the revision values.

Comment: btw, is there any other way to get all the revisions details without looping thru the get item revisions diff?

Comment: Currently, There is No way.

Comment: @MûhámmàdYäsårK This is a huge limitation, I hit the the API rate limit in no time when trying to get all revision differences for a number of items. If an item has 30 revision I need to do 30 API calls... Any plans for this issue?